# Is Spring Framework used in a unit test?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, junit

I am getting ready to take my *Spring Certification v5.0* and there appears to be a question:  **Do you use Spring in a unit test?** [Link to Exam Guide questions](https://d1fto35gcfffzn.cloudfront.net/academy/Core-Spring-5.0-Certification-Study-Guide.pdf).

From [Spring reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testing) I know this:

> The POJOs that make up your application should be testable in JUnit or
>   TestNG tests, with objects simply instantiated using the new operator,
>   **without Spring or any other container**.

From my study as well I can tell that we only are using Spring when testing controllers (like below), repositories or when creating integration tests and maybe some other cases. We would need the TestContext in these cases which is part of **org.springframework.*** package.

> @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
>
> @WebMvcTest(HelloWorldController.class)

So, is the correct answer of this question: *No we do not use Spring?* or that, *Yes we do need it*. Because we obviously use it in some cases.

Comment: @Downvoter: You dont need to downvote just because I'm trying to understand a concept better. :)

Comment: 'using Spring' and 'using a SpringRunner' is not exactly the same

Comment: Hey @Stultuske, you are right, but since SpringRunner is found on springframework package: (org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner), I deduced the fact that we are actually using Spring here; and the test module comes with spring core

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first paragraph you mentioned is the answer to your question, you don't need Spring to write unit tests for the classes you wrote, even when they're Spring beans.

The other cases you mentioned aren't really unit tests. When testing a repository using `SpringRunner` and a mock database, you're no longer writing a unit test, but an **integration test**. The same applies to  writing tests for your controller using `MockMvc`. In both cases you're testing the integration between the Spring framework (Spring MVC or Spring Data) with your code (and a database).

However, you can write unit tests for your controller, but in that case, you would rather do something like this:

```
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public ModelAndView getHello() {
        return new ModelAndView("hello", "title", "hello world");
    }
}

public class HelloWorldControllerTest {
    private HelloWorldController controller;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        controller = new HelloWorldController();
    }

    @Test
    public void getHelloShouldUseHelloView() {
       assertThat(controller.getHello().getViewName()).isEqualTo("hello");
    }

    @Test
    public void getHelloShouldAddATitleModel() {
        assertThat(controller.getHello().getModel()).containsEntry("title", "Hello world");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying!

Comment: @strg No problem! Though I must say that that certification question is pretty vague.

Comment: Actually we might use some parts of a spring-test package in a unit test. In particular **mock** sub-package is provided by a Spring Framework for that purpose. Excerpt from documentation:
_For certain unit testing scenarios, however, the Spring Framework provides mock objects and testing support classes._
But certainly, your unit test doesn't have to depend on/use those classes...

Comment: It's somewhat subjective, but when should controller tests use spring? The above example is a very strict unit test, but in some scenarios I have used mock mvc set up manually, in conjunction with mockito to mock out other classes used and unit tested rest controllers in that way. It doesn't use spring and isn't a "traditional" unit test liel the above, but it tests the controller in a somewhat simulated web environment, i.e. closer to it's real usage than above, avoids the overhead with using spring in a unit test and is still testing in isolation of other classes

Comment: @jbailie1991 It largely depends on what you want to test. Are you purely interested in the calls made within the controller, or do you want to test your controller mapping as well? If you want to test the first, a simple unit test with a mocking framework will be enough. If you want  the latter, you could write a test using mock mvc.

Answer (score 1):

### Spring is a framework. A framework calls you, so by definition, using spring with your controller is an integration point and does not belong in a unit test.

I have successfully been testing my controllers' behaviour without involving spring whatsoever.
I have also tested the controller's annotation successfully by asking spring to mock the controller and invoking the mockMvc.